# Difference between Blender 2.7, 2.79 and 2.8

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, blender

I've been programming for a few years now, and i have recently moved to Unity. I have already developed some games with 3D models and animations not made by me. I would now learn how to create them myself, using Blender. I installed Blender 2.79, and tried to find some good courses to learn how to use it. I found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&index=1) on youtube, which seems to be very accurate and well explained, but it's about a different version: Blender 2.7. Should I take a different course on my same version (even though it might not be as good), or does it not change much between these last versions?

Thank you!

Comment: How about checking out the [Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.79)? In general: Do you think there would be different versions if nothing changed? And finally: What does your question have to do with Unity? If your are asking about compatibility, a certain Unity version might here and there require a certain Blender version. O remember some people having troubles between 2.7 and 2.8 with importing blender files into Unty...

Comment: If you're just starting to learn Blender, I would highly recommend using 2.8 if your computer fulfills the minimum requirements (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). The UI is greatly improved and you won't have to re-learn the UI later on just because you started with 2.79.

Comment: Most of what you learn is easy enough to apply to any version of blender. The biggest user change between 2.80 and older tutorials, apart for the location of items, would be the change of some shortcuts. To get started with 2.80, the blender foundation is releasing a [series of short videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) specifically about 2.80.

Comment: I started with blender using version 2.3 .. almost everything changed layout and positions .. but they added the search function back in 2.5 if I remember correctly so as long as you know how the thing is called you are wanting to do simply hit `space` and search for it ;)

Comment: @rjg thank you, my pc fulfills the **recommended** requirements. I will update to 2.8!

Comment: @sambler I will check that out, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain functionality all three are more or less the same. If you are a beginner you will learn the basic compositions of models, what are verticies, edges and faces and so on. You can apply this knowledge to any version you want really.

The main difference between 2.7, 2.79 and 2.8 are the control schemes. Everything in 2.8 has been made more "streamlined" (my opinion), meaning that if you have any experience with game editors or any other similar product you will know ho to navigate around it. Blender 2.7 and 2.79 are different with a lot of controls seeming weird to newcomers.

So I would say you can watch guides from any version you want, just don't get attached to controls too much. Also 2.8 has a TON of new features specifically for animating drawn sprites so there might be a bit of newer stuff in there. But for the basics andy guide will do.

Hope I helped to clarify this a bit :)

Comment: Thank you very much, exacly the answer i was looking for! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.